# Induction proof of $\sum_{j=0}^n{(-1)^j{n \choose j}\prod_{k=m+1}^{m+n-1}{(j+k)}}=0$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, induction, summation

Does anynone have some hints to prove the following equation by induction for all $n\geq 1$ and $m\in\mathbb{Z} $

$$\sum_{j=0}^n{(-1)^j{n \choose j}\prod_{k=m+1}^{m+n-1}{(j+k)}}=0$$

use for induction step:

$$ {n-1 \choose k-1} + {n-1 \choose k} = {n \choose k} $$

Answer (score 2):

Start with 
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n} (-1)^j \binom{n}{j} (1+x)^{j} = (-x)^n $$

By applying binomial theorem to $(1 - (1+x))^n$.

Now multiply both sides with $(1+x)^{m+n-1}$ and differentiate ... times, and set $x$ to ..., and show by induction that ...

Comment: Of course, this might not be considered a "direct" induction proof and might possibly have issues if $-m \ge n$.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a proof by induction ... this isn't it. Notice

$$\sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j{n \choose j} \left[\prod_{k=m+1}^{m+n-1}{(j+k)}\right]x^{j+m}  =\sum_{j=0}^{n}(-1)^j{n\choose j}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\left(x^{j+m+n-1}\right)$$

What can be done from here?

$$ \begin{array}{l} =\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\left[x^{m+n-1}\sum_{j=0}^n{n\choose j}(-x)^j\right] \\
 =\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}} \left(x^{m+n-1}(1-x)^n\right) \\ 
 =\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{d^{n-1-l}}{dx^{n-1-l}}x^{m+n-1}\right)\left(\frac{d^{\,l}}{dx^l}(1-x)^n\right).\end{array}$$ Now, $\displaystyle\frac{d^{\,l}}{dx^l}(1-x)^n =(-1)^l \left[\prod_{r=n-l+1}^n r\right](1-x)^{n-l}$ and $(1-x)^{n-l}=0$ at $x=1$ when $l<n$.

Comment: Tried to create spoiler text many times (see edit history). Failed. Gave up.

Comment: Spoilers work awfully or don't work at all with double dollar signs or big coding. I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff They [should](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/2433/11763) work with double dollar signs. However, one issue is that the LaTeX spoilers don't work in previews...

Answer (score 0):

We can write the product as a factorial times a binomial and then use [Vandermonde's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu-Vandermonde_identity) to write that as a linear combination of $\binom{j}{i}$:
$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=m+1}^{m+n-1}(j+k)
&=(n-1)!\binom{j+m+n-1}{n-1}\\
&=(n-1)!\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{j}{i}\binom{m+n-1}{n-i-1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
$(1)$ is a degree $n-1$ polynomial in $j$, and in general, the [$n^{\text{th}}$ forward difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#n-th_difference) of a polynomial of degree less than $n$ is $0$. In particular
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^j\binom{n}{j}\prod_{k=m+1}^{m+n-1}(j+k)\\
&=(-1)^n\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^{n-j}\binom{n}{j}\prod_{k=m+1}^{m+n-1}(j+k)\tag{2}\\
&=(-1)^n\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^{n-j}\binom{n}{j}(n-1)!\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{j}{i}\binom{m+n-1}{n-i-1}\tag{3}\\
&=(-1)^n(n-1)!\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{m+n-1}{n-i-1}\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^{n-j}\binom{n}{j}\binom{j}{i}\tag{4}\\
&=(-1)^n(n-1)!\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{m+n-1}{n-i-1}\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^{n-j}\binom{n-i}{n-j}\binom{n}{i}\tag{5}\\
&=(-1)^n(n-1)!\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{m+n-1}{n-i-1}(1-1)^{n-i}\binom{n}{i}\tag{6}\\[12pt]
&=0\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation of Steps:

$(2)$: $(-1)^j=(-1)^n(-1)^{n-j}$

$(3)$: apply $(1)$

$(4)$: rearrange terms

$(5)$: $\displaystyle\binom{n}{j}\binom{j}{i}=\frac{n!}{(n-j)!\,i!\,(j-i)!}=\binom{n}{i}\binom{n-i}{n-j}$

$(6)$: $\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^{n-j}\binom{n-i}{n-j}=(1-1)^{n-i}$

$(7)$: each term in $(6)$ is $0$ since $i\lt n$

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how the first equation conversation works !? What should I know ?

Comment: @fast-forward: [binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) are
$$
\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!\,(n-k)!}
$$
where $n!$ is $n$ [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial). Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=m+1}^{m+n-1}(j+k)
&=\underbrace{(j+m+1)(j+m+2)(j+m+3)\dots(j+m+n-1)}_{n-1\text{ terms}}\\
&=\frac{(j+m+n-1)!}{(j+m)!}\\
&=(n-1)!\frac{(j+m+n-1)!}{(j+m)!\,(n-1)!}\\
&=(n-1)!\binom{j+m+n-1}{n-1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @fast-forward: the next equation is [Vandermonde's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu-Vandermonde_identity). Later, we use
$$
\begin{align}
\binom{n}{j}\binom{j}{i}
&=\frac{n!}{j!\,(n-j)!}\frac{j!}{i!\,(j-i)!}\\
&=\frac{n!}{(n-i)!\,(n-j)!}\frac{(n-i)!}{i!\,(j-i)!}\\
&=\frac{n!}{(n-i)!\,i!}\frac{(n-i)!}{(n-j)!\,(j-i)!}\\
&=\binom{n}{i}\binom{n-i}{n-j}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: thank you, i understand the first part. the next equation "vandermonde identity" i need to understand more

Comment: @fast-forward: I have expanded the explanation. What about Vandermonde is troubling?